# Looking for a SQL result exporter tool for non-tech end users

Tags: web-apps, sql

Six years ago we built a homemade tool for our internal users to download CSV files based on a SQL query.
There is two kind of users :

- **Admins** who can define a SQL query with parameters
- **Users** who can run a query specifying those parameters and download a CSV

I'm looking for a replacement of this tool, so far we have considered Tableau and the data importer feature of Excel. None of them were satisfying.

What I expect from the tool :

- User Friendly & Web based (no need for any local installation)
- Work with Millions of rows
- Doesn't require SQL skill
- Connect with any kind of Database
- Queries can be parameterized

I'm turning around on this since a while.Thank you deeply for your answers.

Comment: What is the structure of your data? Could all of your data fit in a single huge CSV file, and if yes, how many columns would there be?

Comment: You want to run it with particular kind of database(like Postgresql or MySQL) or with `any` database ?

Comment: Usually a single big csv file is fine with up to 30 columns

Comment: Running on Impala in our case